# Stream audio from an authenticated url

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, streaming, html5-audio

I have a external server URL to which I pass credentials and and id to get the audio file like http://myexternalserver.com/?u=xxx&p=xxx&id=xxx

In order to avoid doing this from javascript and **exposing** the credentials to user, I was attempting to call the url from backend and stream it to the UI request(on my server)

```
using (Stream mystream = httpResponse2.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(mystream))
    {
        int length = 2048;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.BufferOutput = true;
        response.ContentType = "audio/wav";
        while((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        response.End();
    }
}
```

Using this approach, I am successfully able to play the stream in an `<audio>` element.

Below are issues which I'm facing:

- While the stream is playing, the seek control bar is always stuck at 0 as audio length is Infinity.Due to this I am unable to use control slider to seek to buffer areas
- When the stream ends, `$("audio")[0].duration` returns 9188187664790.943 (or some huge number for 20 - 30 seconds audio) and audio's display time shows -596523:-14:-8 (while playing this was a number going from 00:01 to 00:24 and then suddenly to a negative number).
- I'm unable to find a solution which will allow seeking into an unbuffered area.

I'm also not quite sure if this is a correct/best approach, so suggestions on approach would also be very helpful.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issues. Were you able to solve them? Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue.

What I did was I examined what my HTTP server responded to requests for regular mp3 files stored on the server statically. I noticed that the server was setting two headers which I missed. Those were `Accept-Ranges: bytes` and `Content-Length: xxx`.

When I set those headers all the issues from the question disappeared.

Hope this will help somebody.

Comment: In my case though, I don't have access to the external server and I am not able to forward the partial content request to that server. I had to use an ugly solution by writing a job to fetch all files to my server and then use the Accept-Ranges solution(serve from my server behind auth). Still haven't been able to remove this overhead. Thanks!